# Is it possible to change a View in MvvMCross without opening a new window?

Tags: macos, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.mac

I'm currently trying to build a simple macos & WPF application with the help of the MvvMCross framework. I'm having some trouble with navigating from one Viewmodel to another. I've got my WPF client currently working as desired, but I can't seem to achieve the same behaviour for my macos client.

Clicking on any navigation button opens a separate window. What I'd like to see is that the content in the current window changes to the content of the view that was navigated towards.

You can find the code over [here](https://github.com/rob-alem/MvvMCross)